# MySQL daily score change with global rank

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a system which records a users total score ("XP") at the end of each day so players can track their progress over time.
At the moment I'm trying to write a query that can return a leaderboard based on the XP change from the previous X days, with a rank. I don't want to build a dedicated leaderboard table as interval X can change.

**EDIT**

I've added a SQL Fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7c1c/9 - Here's a working version without rank
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7c1c/11 - Here's the closest I can get with rank incorporated (this isn't working, but hopefully clear what I'm attempting)

Problems:

- I have a double nested subquery . I don't like this, but couldn't find a way to count the `HAVING BY` clause in the `countsub` subquery without it;
- As a result of the double nested subquery, the `xp_change` column is unavailable in the `countsub` query, so I can't actually compare changes

It seems to me like I've either written the query incorrectly, or I'm missing something. I've been trying to figure out a way to remove the `COUNT` subquery, but haven't had any luck so far. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

**/EDIT**

Here are my schemas:

**accounts**

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `scanned_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `accounts_display_name_index` (`display_name`),
  KEY `accounts_last_tracked_index` (`scanned_at`),
  KEY `accounts_slug_index` (`slug`)
)
```

**account_instances**

The game in question has multiple game types, each with a different leaderboard, and so an account can have multiple "instances":

```
CREATE TABLE `account_instances` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_instances_account_id_game_type_id_unique` (`account_id`,`game_type_id`),
  KEY `account_instances_game_type_id_foreign` (`game_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_instances_game_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`game_type_id`) REFERENCES `game_types` (`id`)
)
```

**stats**

These are the stats which a user can have an XP score in:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stats_name_unique` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stats_display_name_unique` (`display_name`),
  KEY `stats_name_index` (`name`)
)
```

**account_instance_stats**

Associates an account instance and a stat with a score (`xp`) for a given day:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_instance_stats` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_instance_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `xp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_instance_stats_account_instance_id_stat_id_date_unique` (`account_instance_id`,`stat_id`,`date`),
  KEY `account_instance_stats_stat_id_foreign` (`stat_id`),
  KEY `account_instance_stats_xp_index` (`xp`),
  KEY `account_instance_stats_date_index` (`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_instance_stats_account_instance_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`account_instance_id`) REFERENCES `account_instances` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_instance_stats_stat_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`stat_id`) REFERENCES `stats` (`id`)
)
```

Here is the query I have written so far. It won't run, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying here:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    SUM(ais.xp - ais2.xp) AS xp_change,
    (
        select count(*) FROM
        (
            SELECT COUNT(sub.id)
                FROM account_instance_stats AS sub 
                LEFT JOIN account_instance_stats sub2 
                    ON sub.account_instance_id = sub2.account_instance_id 
                    AND sub.stat_id = sub2.stat_id 
                    AND sub2.date = date_sub(sub.date, INTERVAL 1 day)  
                JOIN account_instances AS ai ON sub.account_instance_id = ai.id 
                WHERE ai.game_type_id = 1
                AND sub.date = curdate()
                AND sub.stat_id = 1
                GROUP BY sub.id
                HAVING SUM(sub.xp - sub2.xp) > xp_change
        ) AS countsub
    ) AS rank

    FROM account_instance_stats AS ais 
    LEFT JOIN account_instance_stats ais2 
        ON ais.account_instance_id = ais2.account_instance_id 
        AND ais.stat_id = ais2.stat_id 
        AND ais2.date = date_sub(ais.date, INTERVAL 1 day)  
    JOIN account_instances AS ai ON ais.account_instance_id = ai.id 
    JOIN accounts AS a ON ai.account_id = a.id
    WHERE ai.game_type_id = 1
    AND ais.date = curdate()
    AND ais.stat_id = 1
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY rank DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

The bulk of the parent query is a `left join` on `account_instance_stats` to itself based on the interval so I can compare the `xp` column for the two dates. This bit works as expected. The part I'm struggling with is the `rank` subquery. This pretty much performs the same query but calculates the rank by counting how many accounts have a higher `xp_change`.

Thanks!

Comment: You have too much information listed, which overwhelms your problem statement. For instance, you could replace the CREATE TABLE statements, with a simple list of non-trivial columns for each table (e.g., updated_at is a trivial column.) Then show sample data, and what your expected end result would look like. You could also build a SQLFiddle.com configuration, making it easier for people to provide you a solution.

Comment: Is the "rank" the position of the row returned in your first query? (i.e., in your sqlfiddle, player_3 is rank#1, player_1 is rank#2 and player_2 is rank#3?) If so, I would either do that at the presentation layer (since you are returning an ordered list) or use a MySQL variable.

Comment: In future I want to be able to constrain by account_instance_id and return the rank, without the need to return all rows and count in my presentation layer. Therefore, I'd like to be able to calculate the rank in the query itself based on how many rows have a higher xp_change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a solution that uses SQL variables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7c1c/22)

Which shows this code.

```
SELECT *, @rank := COALESCE(@rank + 1, 1) AS ranking
FROM (
  SELECT a.ID AS ID, a.display_name AS display_name
   , SUM(ais.xp - ais2.xp) AS xp_change
  FROM accounts AS a 
  JOIN account_instances AS ai 
    ON ai.account_id = a.id
  JOIN account_instance_stats AS ais 
    ON ais.account_instance_id = ai.id 
  LEFT JOIN account_instance_stats ais2 
    ON ais.account_instance_id = ais2.account_instance_id 
       AND ais.stat_id = ais2.stat_id 
       AND ais2.date = date_sub(ais.date, INTERVAL 1 day) 
  WHERE ai.game_type_id = 1
       AND ais.date = '2016-06-02'
       AND ais.stat_id = 1
  GROUP BY a.id
  ORDER BY xp_change DESC) AS t1
```

I rearranged your table JOIN order to (IMO) a more logical order.

Given this solution: if you want to a single account (assume ID=2), I would change the code to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, @rank := COALESCE(@rank + 1, 1) AS ranking
  FROM (
    SELECT a.ID AS ID, a.display_name AS display_name
     , SUM(ais.xp - ais2.xp) AS xp_change
    FROM accounts AS a 
    JOIN account_instances AS ai 
      ON ai.account_id = a.id
    JOIN account_instance_stats AS ais 
      ON ais.account_instance_id = ai.id 
    LEFT JOIN account_instance_stats ais2 
      ON ais.account_instance_id = ais2.account_instance_id 
         AND ais.stat_id = ais2.stat_id 
         AND ais2.date = date_sub(ais.date, INTERVAL 1 day) 
    WHERE ai.game_type_id = 1
         AND ais.date = '2016-06-02'
         AND ais.stat_id = 1
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY xp_change DESC) AS t1
) AS foo
WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. Thanks so much for your help and solution!